# Error in starting tomcat 7.0.52

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am facing problem in starting up the tomcat zip file. I am totally new to jsp and servlets. I have installed tomcat 7.0.52 and set the path and java_home both. In one of my system its working fine but in another system with same configuration its creating trouble i don't know why. I have installed the installer earlier of tomcat but now i have uninstall it and download the zip of tomcat. So now i am facing the following exception i guess the problem is the tomcat is not able to deploy its existing projects. I have searched across the web but i am not able to figure it out.

```
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4
.8.
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], ra
ndom [true].
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializ
eSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2525 ms
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\ap
ache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\docs
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-window
s-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\docs
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(Contex
tConfig.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836
)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
a:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig
.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.idFor(DigesterFacto
ry.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.<clinit>(DigesterFa
ctory.java:59)
    ... 18 more

Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\ap
ache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\examples
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-window
s-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\examples
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.uti
l.descriptor.DigesterFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(Contex
tConfig.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:382)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
a:1229)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig
.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\ap
ache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\host-manager
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-window
s-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\host-manager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.uti
l.descriptor.DigesterFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(Contex
tConfig.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:382)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
a:1229)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig
.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\ap
ache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\manager
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-window
s-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\manager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.uti
l.descriptor.DigesterFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(Contex
tConfig.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:382)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
a:1229)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig
.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\ap
ache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\ROOT
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-window
s-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\ROOT
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.uti
l.descriptor.DigesterFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(Contex
tConfig.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:382)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
a:1229)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig
.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 06, 2014 11:04:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 227 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `native` directory from `bin`. Or try to download architecture-independent bundle, not `x86`.